# Como mudar a cor do botão flutuante e inserir um texto nele

Tags: android, android-layout

Gostaria de alterar a cor do botão flutuante e colocar um pequeno texto mas não sei como fazer, poderiam me ajudar

Comment: Qual botão flutuante? Procure postar um [mcve] que auxilie no entendimento da sua dificuldade, ou ao menos o trecho relevante do seu código atual.

Answer (score 1):

melhor se voce fazer isso programaticamente,por exemplo, em um evento qualquer da sua activity vc pode fazer:

```
public class MinhaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button meubotao;
    // ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        meubotao = (Buttom) findViewById(R.id.meubotaonoxml);
        // aqui voce pode mudar a cor original, uma imagem, um shape num xml, em fim o que voce quiser
        if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
           meubotao.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.meufundo) );
        } else {
           meubotao.setBackground( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.meufundo));
        }
        // especificamente nesse caso, eu verifico a versão do android para evitar problemas
        // você pode usar o mesmo recurso em qualquer evento que voce quiser, pois a forma para setar o background de um compnente no android via código é essa
        // se voce quiser mudar a cor, basta colocar a cor que voce deseja usando uma referencia no seu "/values/colors.xml" ou mesmo a cor como uma string usando parsecolor:
        meubotao.setBackground(getColor(getApplicatioContext(), Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")));
    }
}
```

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar a linha **backgroundTint**, exemplo:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/orange"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:fabSize="normal" >
```

Lembre-se que essa linha não começa com **android:** e sim com **app:**

Para adicionar um texto no lugar da imagem, é um pouco mais complicado, você precisa inclui-lo dentro de um FrameLayout.

Exemplo:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:color/transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@android:string/ok"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</FrameLayout>
```